# Change css style field from single-line text to droplist

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm currently recreating our forms in Sitecore 9.3 Forms and am trying to change the field style input from single line text to a droplist that points to a folder containing style items. WFFM used to have this functionality but I can't seem to find any clear way to do it in 9.3.

I've tried changing the template but that doesn't change the form builder input nor does it pass through to the form if editing in the content tree.

[image: Sitecore 9.3 Forms Field Style]

[image: Sitecore 8.2 WFFM Field Style]